# SD-WAN vs MPLS VPN

Tags: layer2, layer3, mpls, mpls-vpn

Citing wikipedia on [MPLS VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPLS_VPN)

> There are three types of MPLS VPNs deployed in networks today: 1.
>   Point-to-point (Pseudowire) 2. Layer 2 (VPLS) 3. Layer 3 (VPRN)

I am confused about the difference between SD-WAN and MPLS-VPN types mentioned above (I know the difference between SD-WAN and MPLS) but this the MPLS-VPN is confusing me. Any clarification is much appreciated.

Comment: SD-WAN is not a protocol (or set of protocols), but a deployment technique.  So I don't see how you can compare them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ron already mentioned this in the comments but let me try to offer a little more explanation.

SD-WAN, from a vendor perspective,  is offered as a solution which involve a set of technologies designed to simplify deployment and traffic management over WAN. It's a child of the "SDN" umbrella, and basically means you would have software doing a lot of automation for you for device provisioning(instead of a NE popping into the hardware and configuring the CLI) and you(the user) can manage a lot of things(mostly) from a dashboard. Capabilities offered as part of solution vary by vendors.
Viptella's vEdge, CISCO's IWAN, VMWare's VeloCloud are some examples of this.

MPLS VPN, on the other hand, is a VPN created over a MPLS underlay. This VPN can allow you to route packets ( L3 VPN ) or switch frames ( pseudowire, VPLS ).

Comment: now it is much more clear. I am assuming the NE will have to be more involved in MPLS VPN as compared to SD-WAN, right?